# What will happen to a human if he/she falls down into particle accelerator?

Tags: particle-physics, biophysics

I saw a TV series [The Flash](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3107288/) which is about physics fiction.

What happens if a human comes into contact with a bombardment of particles in a particle accelerator?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about fictional physics.

Comment: is fictional physic out of physic?

Comment: delete potion does not work

Answer (score 8):

It can transfer energy to a Human and produce [injuries and death](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatoli_Bugorski) - no superpowers.

Comment: Also people who have been nuked in real life tend not to end up like The Hulk

Answer (score 4):

First of all particle accelerators (LHC for example) have a lot radiation packed into it perhaps enough to kill you pretty quickly.

Next, if you think a **single** proton may give you super-powers your wrong, in space for example astronauts get hit by particles that have many magnitude of more energy than that of LHC beam (most powerful particle accelerator currently built) yet they do not show significant radiation doses, besides a single proton is most likely to avoid all atoms of tissues and other atoms and go straight through your body as if it did not even exist, even if it did smash into an atom of your body, not much harm is done.

Furthermore, there has been a case when [Anatoli Bugorski](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatoli_Bugorski), an Russian Scientist was struck with a proton beam and he had the proton beam that had burned through parts of his face, his bone, and the brain tissue underneath. His face was swollen beyond recognition shortly after the incident.

Now keep in mind, this happened 1978, while the accelerators lacked the power that is available with our modern day accelerators for example LHC.

If you think that was bad, if you get hit by LHC your likely to suffer very fatal life-long injury and most likely death. LHC proton beam has so much energy to evaporate the bodies water instantly to give you a better estimate the proton beam has 362 MJ

This is enough to melt 498.4 kg of copper that is only 1 beam alone, now imagine 2 beams hitting you, it has potential energy that can be released to melt 1 tonne of copper. Your more than likely going the die instantly. Or more scarier approach is that LHC has 77.4 kg of TNT worth of energy that is 1 beam, together they have the double.

Most likely your face would be completely destroyed.

Rather than have super-powers or any sort of mutation. I'm sorry to say but the radiation doses and energy potential are far too powerful now in particle accelerators, to survive.

For those interested in references of the Energy of LHC beam: http://lhc-machine-outreach.web.cern.ch/lhc-machine-outreach/beam.htm

Comment: thanks for the answer!!! I was really  hoping such  answer

Comment: What is a "very fatal life-long injury"?

Comment: @bukko, when I mean "very fatal life-long injury" I mean, injuries such as as long-term Symptomatic epilepsy as a result of brain damage, or stroke (although unlikely to happen in such accident but still possible) which is fatal but also has long term implications such as partial paralysis. Furthermore, fatal doses of radiation may cause sterilization which can not only be fatal at the incident but also sterilization can be thought of as life-long injury.

Answer (score 2):

Do you remember how spiderman originally go his powers? Or the Hulk? Spiderman was bitten by a radioactive spider and Bruce Banner (the Hulk) was bombarded by a large amount of gamma radiation. These were superhero characters created in the advent of the age of nuclear power at a time when the average person didn't much understand what radiation was. Today, you and I know that radiation kills people in large doses and that a "radioactive spider" would more likely poison you with radioisotopes than give you the ability to climb walls. But when these characters were first created, radiation was a new and less widely understood phenomenon and made for a great way to "believably" give these men superpowers.

Today, radiation doesn't fly so well as an explanation. So writers again turn to new and less widely understood science. Supercolliders, particle accelerators, and similar scientific technology is ideal for them. With the Higg's boson recently discovered, most people have now at least heard of a particle accelerator but less really know what they are or how they work. So they are convenient to act as the mysterious source of superpowers just as radiation worked back when the Hulk or Spiderman first came out.

In the future, I assume that more and more of the general public will understand what a particle accelerator is and how it works. When that happens, writers will again have to find a new source of superpowers for their characters. I have no idea what that will be. Why will they always have to search for and use the newest sciences? Because superpowers are fictional. They are trying to find a believable way of doing the impossible. No one can run at speeds comparable to the Flash, it's just not possible. But if they say he got his powers by getting rubbed by a magnet, everybody would be like "that doesn't make sense. Magnets don't do that!" Even though super-speed like the Flash's doesn't make sense anyway.

Point is, no, particle accelerators won't give you superpowers. Nothing will give a person superpowers (except money for a Batman-like superhero). Particle accelerators are just the latest in a long history of convenient explanations to the general public for how the impossible happened.

Comment: At least in the Marvel universe, most superheroes didn't get powers from radiation, they are [mutants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutant_(Marvel_Comics)).

Comment: @KyleKanos Yeah, mutants, aliens, magic. All these are better than trying to use scientific intervention. Magic is probably the best because you can never say "No way, magic can't do that."